# How to define a default value for a field of a FileHelpers element class

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I'm trying to load a CSV file (delims are ';' and quotes are '"').

I have successfully created everything (the wizard tool is awesome), but there's one thing that I can't find a solution for.

Basically, I have an integer (System.Int32) column. In theory *most* of the records will have a *positive integer value* in that column. Sometimes, however, I might encounter a value "N/A" in that column. What I want to achieve, is have FileHelpers assign a default value (-1 works just fine), when it encounters "N/A" in that column.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

PS: I might need to do the same for a System.DateTime field (it might also have "N/A" sometimes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way that comes to mind to do what you want would be to use the `FieldConverter` attribute on those fields and create custom converter classes that assign the default value you want the field to have.

You need to create a class that inherits `ConverterBase`, and then provide implementations for the two virtual methods, `StringToField()` and `FieldToString()`.

In the `FieldToString()` method, you'll check to see if the string is equal to "N/A". If it is, return the default value you want.

You will need two different classes, one that can handle `Int32` and one that can handle `DateTime`.

The FileHelpers documentation has an example of how to do this. [Link](http://www.filehelpers.com/example_customconv.html)

Answer (score 5):

Like Brandon said u need to use this converter

```
// In your class
[FieldConverter(typeof(NoValueConverter))]
public int Number;

// Te Converter
public class NoValueConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string sourceString)
    {
       if (sourceString.Trim().ToUpper() == "N/A")
        return -1; // or int.MinValue;
       else
        return Integer.Parse(sourceString);
    }

    public override string FieldToString(object fieldValue)
    {
        return fieldValue.ToString();
    }

}
```

We are glad that u liked the wizard :) (we are working a cool autodetection feature to make it more easy to create the mapping class)

Comment: since from is a LINQ keyword, should a different parameter name be used, or won't that matter?

Comment: Your are right Matt :) edited now, thanks

Maybe I must to update the sample code of the library that was created for .net 2.0 before from where a reserved keyword.