# FileHelpers Read Int "NA"

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am trying to read in a CSV file using using FileHelpers (C#).  I have an int column.  However, when the file is invalid/missing it has "NA".  In this case, I would like the behavior to be to have these retain the default value of 0.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please share your code snippet to read the CSV and some sample CSV data?

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007018/how-to-define-a-default-value-for-a-field-of-a-filehelpers-element-class (Not an exact duplicate, but I believe it provides a solution for you)

Comment: Ah yes, that answers my question thank you!  A converter does the trick... thanks much!!!